# Extension methods for Daylight Savings Time dates

Tags: c#, datetime, extension-methods

Just wondering if anyone had any suggestions for improvements. I created these extension methods so it's easier to get the start and end dates of Daylight Savings Time from the `TimeZoneInfo` class.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule in effect for the given year.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="timeZoneInfo"></param>
    /// <param name="year"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule GetAdjustmentRuleForYear(this TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo, int year)
    {
        TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule[] adjustments = timeZoneInfo.GetAdjustmentRules();
        // Iterate adjustment rules for time zone 
        foreach (TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule adjustment in adjustments)
        {
            // Determine if this adjustment rule covers year desired 
            if (adjustment.DateStart.Year <= year && adjustment.DateEnd.Year >= year)
            {
                return adjustment;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Daylight Savings Time start date for the given year.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="adjustmentRule"></param>
    /// <param name="year"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DateTime GetDaylightTransitionStartForYear(this TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule adjustmentRule, int year)
    {
        return adjustmentRule.DaylightTransitionStart.GetDateForYear(year);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Daylight Savings Time end date for the given year.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="adjustmentRule"></param>
    /// <param name="year"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DateTime GetDaylightTransitionEndForYear(this TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule adjustmentRule, int year)
    {
        return adjustmentRule.DaylightTransitionEnd.GetDateForYear(year);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the date of the transition for the given year.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="transitionTime"></param>
    /// <param name="year"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DateTime GetDateForYear(this TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime transitionTime, int year)
    {
        if (transitionTime.IsFixedDateRule)
        {
            return GetFixedDateRuleDate(transitionTime, year);
        }
        else
        {
            return GetFloatingDateRuleDate(transitionTime, year);
        }
    }

    private static DateTime GetFixedDateRuleDate(TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime transitionTime, int year)
    {
        return new DateTime(year,
                           transitionTime.Month,
                           transitionTime.Day,
                           transitionTime.TimeOfDay.Hour,
                           transitionTime.TimeOfDay.Minute,
                           transitionTime.TimeOfDay.Second,
                           DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
    }

    private static DateTime GetFloatingDateRuleDate(TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime transitionTime, int year)
    {
        // For non-fixed date rules, get local calendar
        Calendar localCalendar = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;

        // Get first day of week for transition
        // For example, the 3rd week starts no earlier than the 15th of the month
        int startOfWeek = transitionTime.Week * 7 - 6;

        // What day of the week does the month start on?
        int firstDayOfWeek = (int)localCalendar.GetDayOfWeek(new DateTime(year, transitionTime.Month, 1));

        // Determine how much start date has to be adjusted
        int transitionDay;
        int changeDayOfWeek = (int)transitionTime.DayOfWeek;
        if (firstDayOfWeek <= changeDayOfWeek)
            transitionDay = startOfWeek + (changeDayOfWeek - firstDayOfWeek);
        else
            transitionDay = startOfWeek + (7 - firstDayOfWeek + changeDayOfWeek);

        // Adjust for months with no fifth week
        if (transitionDay > localCalendar.GetDaysInMonth(year, transitionTime.Month))
            transitionDay -= 7;

        return new DateTime(year, 
                   transitionTime.Month, 
                   transitionDay,
                   transitionTime.TimeOfDay.Hour,
                   transitionTime.TimeOfDay.Minute,
                   transitionTime.TimeOfDay.Second,
                   DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick comment: `ExtensionMethods` is a rather vague name for a class. Remember that these methods can also be called as *static methods* - hence, I'd suggest you rename it to `TimeZones`, so you can call `TimeZones.GetAdjustmentRuleForYear(foo, 2014);`... or perhaps `TimeZoneExtensions` would be better. In any case, `ExtensionMethods` is too vague for such a specialized class.

Comment: No offense, but this is not a situation where you should roll your own. [This is why.](http://youtu.be/-5wpm-gesOY)

Comment: That's a good suggestion about the class name. It was just something I threw together for testing but I'm guilty of not using a specific name in other cases. And unfortunately, I don't have a choice about working with time zones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Room for improvement:

- `ExtensionMethods` is a terrible name. What are we extending? We're extending the `TimeZoneInfo` class, so we should probably call our extension methods something like `TimeZoneExtensions`. There are [lots of options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412425/naming-an-extension-method-class) for naming schemes. Pick one you like.
- `GetAdjustmentRuleForYear` can return null. I'm not a fan of that. What's worse is the XML doc doesn't even mention it. You should at least document it, but I would personally at least *consider* throwing an exception.
- Speaking of `null`, it's possible for `this` to be null, so you should also consider checking for it.
- This is a pretty useless comment. It serves no purpose but to clutter the code.

  > ```
  >  // Iterate adjustment rules for time zone 
  > foreach (TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule adjustment in adjustments)
  > ```
- `firstDayOfWeek` is a misleading name. It looks like it's really the first day of the month. I suggest `firstWeedayOfMonth` instead.

  > ```
  >  // What day of the week does the month start on?
  > int firstDayOfWeek = (int)localCalendar.GetDayOfWeek(new DateTime(year, transitionTime.Month, 1));
  > ```
- If you need a comment to say *what*, you generally need to extract a well named method instead.

  > ```
  > // Determine how much start date has to be adjusted
  > int transitionDay;
  > int changeDayOfWeek = (int)transitionTime.DayOfWeek;
  > if (firstDayOfWeek <= changeDayOfWeek)
  >     transitionDay = startOfWeek + (changeDayOfWeek - firstDayOfWeek);
  > else
  >     transitionDay = startOfWeek + (7 - firstDayOfWeek + changeDayOfWeek);
  > ```
- That statement could also use some braces in my opinion.

### What I like:

- Use of XML docs on public methods.
- You've generally used pretty good names (other than ones I've mentioned).
- It's fairly readable code.
- Methods are short and to the point with the exception of `GetFixedDateRuleDate`.